# Is there a signing with google apps OAuth2 embeddable widget like this is for Google+?

Tags: google-oauth

Specifically at the top of this page:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login there is:

[image]

It looks great, but when I change the scope it's still in the context of Google+ and I would like to just sign in with google apps and ask for the contact permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no embeddable widget that does not include the G+ scopes. The page you reference explains how you can do a basic login authentication via OAuth2 without other scopes but there is not a widgetized implementation.

In general, the simplest approach is to do use the G+ widgets.

Comment: Clarifying what Adam said, you can still use the Google Plus Sign-In with Google Apps users (they work like @gmail accounts if they have turned on Google+). And you can add the contacts scope to that flow by adding the scope in the widget config. However, use of that JS button requires that your site also use the social features. You can continue to use the plain OAuth2 Login scope as documented and add contacts. In that case, you have to create the link on your site to start the flow.